# Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: c#, ssl, authentication

This happens on the `sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate,
                    true, SslProtocols.Default, true);`
call.

I'm trying to do client authentification. I control both client and server, both are c# via sslstream.
When I use a nodejs server, it works perfectly. But I just cant get the serverside to reliably work in c# for some reason. Clearly the ssl authentification needs to wait for the client to choose the client certificate, but apparently this is not a built in feature for c# sslstream class?
I already tried doing this before the call, but it still *immediately* errors out on the call:

[image]

I dont mind the security question in IE. That's fine. I'm concerned with the fact how sslstream does not seem to work at all with such a basic szenario.

Error from wcf trace:

> System.Net Error: 0 : [7928] Exception in AppDomain#13869071::UnhandledExceptionHandler - Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream..
>      at System.Net.Security.SslState.ValidateCreateContext(Boolean isServer, String targetHost, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, X509Certificate serverCertificate, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, Boolean remoteCertRequired, Boolean checkCertRevocationStatus, Boolean checkCertName)
>      at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(X509Certificate serverCertificate, Boolean clientCertificateRequired, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)

Comment: may be because of this, not sure how to solve: The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate

Comment: ok that was it, i disabled clr check.

Comment: hm no, IE still causes this problem on my serverside. I added the wcf trace

Comment: ok apparently this is an error that is thrown on any auth error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication failed because remote party has closed the transport stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664566/authentication-failed-because-remote-party-has-closed-the-transport-stream)

Answer (score 3):

Adding the below code helped me overcome the issue (I'm running the app in .NET 4.5.1).

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

Comment: For me it was Tls12, still great answer.