# Error on production server

Tags: c#, http, ssl, httpwebrequest

Am getting this error when i deploy my app to production server while in my local machine its working well

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected er
>       or occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed becaus
>        the remote party has closed the transport stream.
>          at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readByte
>       , AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>          at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtoco
>       Request asyncRequest)
>          at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolTok
>       n message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>          at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count,
>       syncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>          at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, 
>          at zz.Program.Main(String[] args)

This part of the code

```
   string MsgType = "cmpi_authenticate";
    string Version = "1.7";
    XElement elem = new XElement("CardinalMPI",
        new XElement("MsgType", MsgType),
        new XElement("Version", Version),
        new XElement("ProcessorId", ProcessorId),
        new XElement("MerchantId", MerchantId),
        new XElement("TransactionPwd", TransactionPwd),
        new XElement("TransactionType", TransactionType),
        new XElement("TransactionId", TransactionId),
        new XElement("PAResPayload", PAResPayload)
       );

    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    postData.Append("cmpi_msg=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(elem.ToString()));

    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData.ToString());
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Timeout = 30 * 1000;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    //newStream.Flush();
    //newStream.Close();
    //request.KeepAlive = false;

    string resText = "";
    //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
    //**this is the point of failure**
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        using (StreamReader rs = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), enc))
        {
            resText = rs.ReadToEnd();
            //Console.WriteLine("RES:" + resText);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if the answer here will help, specifically the registry key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35321007/1489570

Comment: I already tried upgrading to 4.6 and also using System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls but its still not working