# azure-iot-hub System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: azure-iot-hub

C# , Net Framework 4.7.2, I have built a connection to Azure IoT Hub using the provided device SDK's. My application functions as expected when running on a Win 10 OS. When I run my application on Win 7 I receive this exception:

Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client.ProvisioningTransportException: HTTP transport exception ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

With some research I fount that it may be due to the security protocol type, but I did not set the protocol type explicitly like the reference below state:

[Authentication failed because remote party has closed the transport stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664566/authentication-failed-because-remote-party-has-closed-the-transport-stream)

What I am using is a SecurityProviderSymmetricKey to build a connection to the DPS.

I also verified that my Win 7 machine had TLS 1.2 enabled, since based on what I have researched it is not enable by default, & I still receive the exception.

What I also found it that the device SDK does not allow you to specify the protocol, & it uses the default of the machine.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/master/configure_tls_protocol_version_and_ciphers.md

Any ideas on to why it would be building the connection properly on Win 10 and not Win 7?
Any ideas on changes that need to be made, or how I can troubleshoot this issue further?

Comment: Could you include a small code snippet to make it easier for others to reproduce? Very excellent writeup btw, thanks for including your research!

Comment: did you able to resolve these issue? if so please share me details