# SecurityProtocol e.g. Tls, Tls11, Tls12, Ssl3 is not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am calling third party WCF service to my .net core 3.1 WEB API application. It was working fine then immediately it gives to start the following exception
"The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."

Inner exception:
"Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."

I tried all SecurityProtocol e.g. Tls, Tls11, Tls12, Ssl3 but no one is working.
How to connect with third party wcf service?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication failed because remote party has closed the transport stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664566/authentication-failed-because-remote-party-has-closed-the-transport-stream)

Comment: No, this answer is not working. I tried all SecurityProtocol e.g. Tls, Tls11, Tls12, Ssl3 but no one is working.